# Negating a statement with "=" in it.

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I am trying to negate this following statement:  $(\forall y)(\exists x)[y = f(x)]$ 
I negated the statement but stopped at  the $\neg[y = f(x)]$ part. I wasn't to sure how to negate it when it came to an equal sign, my thinking would have been replacing "=" with "Not equals($\neq$)", is it okay to leave the negation of $\neg[y = f(x)]$ the way it is or that's a big NO NO? Here is my progressions so far:
$$ = (\exists y)\neg\Big[(\exists x)[y = f(x)]\Big]$$
$$ = (\exists y)(\forall x)\neg[y = f(x)]$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's okay to use $\neq {}$.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks.

Comment: @KonoDioDa Note, $x \neq y$ is usually *by definition* $\neg(x = y)$ in which case you aren't actually doing anything. In other words, $x = y$ is treated just like any other atomic predicate $P(x,y)$ which is to say there is no rule (or need) to "simplify" its negation.

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't you continue that way you had been thinking? It would have been correct.

Comment: I thought it would have be more complex than that haha. Thanks.